# DataBinding RadioButton IsSelected only works once

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, radio-button

I have a problem with data binding. I am using MVVM Light.

When I set a breakpoint on the setter of one of the bools in my view model and select the corresponding radio button, the debugger halts and all looks fine.

Then when I continue, select the other radio button and select the first radio button again, the debugger is not halting. What is going wrong?

I have two two radiobuttons:

```
            <RadioButton  Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Content="Browser cookies" GroupName="loginmethod" IsChecked="{Binding IsBrowserCookiesChecked}"/>
            <RadioButton  Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" Content="Username + password" GroupName="loginmethod" IsChecked="{Binding IsUsernamePasswordChecked}"/>
```

I have bounded them to two separate bools in my view model which looks as follows:

```
   public const string IsUsernamePasswordCheckedPropertyName = "IsUsernamePasswordChecked";

    private bool _isUsernamePasswordChecked = false;
    public bool IsUsernamePasswordChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _isUsernamePasswordChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isUsernamePasswordChecked == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(IsUsernamePasswordCheckedPropertyName);
            _isUsernamePasswordChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(IsUsernamePasswordCheckedPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public const string IsBrowserCookiesCheckedPropertyName = "IsBrowserCookiesChecked";

    private bool _isBrowserCookiesChecked = true;

    public bool IsBrowserCookiesChecked    
    {
        get
        {
            return _isBrowserCookiesChecked;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isBrowserCookiesChecked == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanging(IsBrowserCookiesCheckedPropertyName);
            _isBrowserCookiesChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(IsBrowserCookiesCheckedPropertyName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that when you're doing databinding on radio buttons it's a lot easier to give each button a different `GroupName` so they don't affect each other, then handle the setting and unsetting of each radio button choice via binding only. For example you could expose just one boolean on your viewmodel, have one radio button bind to that bool, then have the other bind to the same one, but with a [inverse boolean converter](https://vidcoder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#VidCoder/Converters/InverseBoolConverter.cs). Or make the property an enum, then assign each radio button to that property, but with an [enum to boolean converter](https://vidcoder.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#VidCoder/Converters/EnumBoolConverter.cs). Then you have the added benefit of fewer properties to worry about on your viewmodel.

When you give radio buttons the same GroupName WPF will try to mess with the other properties every time you change one and you can get some ugly loops and weird behavior.

Comment: Hi RandomEngy, Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work either. The setters are just called once, regardless of the groupname. I removed the groupname as you said, but then WPF sets the name implicity it seems, as the behaviour didn't change. Then I set two different groupnames. This resulted in the both radiobuttons set after clicking both and no way to unset any longer.

Comment: It's not just having different group names. You also need to have the different radiobuttons bind to the same property (with an inversion converter on one).